# Rails multiple dividers in a Ruby on Rails form Selector_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a selector within a standard ruby on rails form. The selector is for countries and the dividers with be continents. But I don't want to hard code the values of the countries in. I am returning several lists of countries (one for each continent) from the controller. And I want to put that in there instead of the hard coded array.

What I have:

***HTML***

```
  <%  grouped_options = [['North America',['USA','Mexico']],['Europe',['Denmark','Germany','France']]] %>

  <%= f.select :country_id, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options), {:include_blank => "Please select a country"}, {:required => true, :class => "white_background"} %>
```

what I want:

```
   <%  grouped_options = [['North America',@north_america_names],['Europe',@europe_names]] %>
```

**Edit:**
This option is not working and I am not sure why?

***Controller***

```
   @north_america_names = Country.select(:name, :id).where("continent = 'North America').distinct
   @europe_names = Country.select(:name, :id).where("continent = 'Europe').distinct
```

The controller works great, it returns a list of names and ids.

**Edit 2:**

This is what I had before (with no dividers) and it worked great as well.

***HTML***

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:country, @country_list, :id, :name, {:include_blank => "Please select a country"}, {:required => true, :class => "white_background"}) %>
```

***Controller***

```
 @country_list = Country.select(:name, :id).all
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oh right, My question is how do I make the second option work. it seems to just insert object references, not names.

Comment: You likely need `to_a` to convert activerecord query object to array. `@north_america_names.to_a`

Comment: I tried the .to_a and it didn't seem to have any affect on what was displayed in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show iterate your `data` which is coming from `@north_america_names` and `@europe_names`

```
<%  grouped_options = [['North America',@north_america_names.collect {|v| [ v.name, v.id ] }],['Europe',@europe_names.collect {|v| [ v.name, v.id ] }]] %>
```